# Where to report back about optimal settings for the script provided in an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, answered-questions

To one of my questions, I got an answer that was what I was looking for. The [script provided](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396856/88814) requires a few input values and I tested different settings to see which one is the most efficient (this in fact was my question: how to solve the task as efficient as possible). Getting the best result ("best" meaning here: reduce processing time as much as possible) depends very much on the settings of input parameters. So to see which input parameters affects the result most, a more substantial report about the tests/results is necessary.

So the question arises: I would like to report the results of my testing back. However: where should I do that?

Based on what you can do at GIS SE, there are different possibilities and I'm not sure where to do that best. I guess option 3 (adding another answer) would be best one:

1. Add a comment. However, comments are limited in length and formatting and also, site policy mentions that intense use of comments is not desired.
2. Edit the answer and add my information there. However, it would mean to intervene in the answer posted by the user and substantially modifying the content of that user's answer. I would not like to see my answers being edited in this way.
3. Adding another answer that refers in fact more to the answer of another user and only indirectly to the question. However, this answer helps to find the best settings to resolve the original problem, so probably this is the best way to do that.
4. Posting another question, refering to the answer I got on my first question. However, as my initial question was how to make my task as efficient as possible, the new question would be in fact some kind of repetition of the first question. And to understand the answer, people still had first to go back to the initial post, read the question + answer there to understand the new question + added answer. So anyhow it would not be a "new", indipendent question that stands for itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my personal opinion of what should be done (or shouldn't be) based on your 4 options.

1. Don't add as a comment, treat comments as temporary
2. Adding your solution to an answer can be acceptable, I have seen it done both here and Stack Overflow.  Typically as a horizontal line and then additional content rather than modifying the answer to change what the answerer has given.
3. **This is the option I prefer** - a) mark the answer as accepted and up-voting, and then b) self-answering (in addition to that accepted answer) to provide the final solution, referencing that it was based off the accepted answer
4. An additional question is a duplicate of your original and should be closed and marked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I agree with [@Midavalo's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5280/107424) and prefer that option too. It is the way I personally would do it *(and already have done so in the past)*. However, in this particular case I have just added further explanations on the runtime and settings including an example as well to my answer. *Therefore also removed my comments.* So in this particular case, feel free to add your experience to this section of the answer, **if** you prefer that option.

Answer (score 1):

I have now posted my feedback as a separate answer, as this seems to be the prefered way to do it: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/398134/88814